# Unable to fetch the latest inserted record using HIBERNATE

Tags: hibernate

I am not able to get the latest inserted value from the table, am using hibernate for my database interaction. if i run the same query in the toad I am able the see that the value is already inserted in database can anyone help me out with this issue.

I have used the below code

```
String hql = "SELECT ID FROM T_ALM_RELEASES WHERE REL_ID="+relId+" AND PROJECT_ID="+projectId;
log.info("query::::::::::::::"+hql);
query = session.createSQLQuery(hql);
//query.addEntity(TAlmReleases.class);
result = (Integer)query.uniqueResult();

if(result==0){
    log.info(" not getting  id for release id::"+relId+" and project id::"+projectId);
}
```

Comment: it may be because you are using the uniqueResult  that means the query expects the only one result, if it is more than one result it will not show. Make sure that the condition  **WHERE REL_ID="+relId+" AND PROJECT_ID="+projectId;** returns only one row

Comment: i have checked the database i have only one value with that insert.i think the query is not hitting the database. is there any other way to fetch the data in from database for the above case

Comment: can you try printing the SQL (in hibernate configuration make show_sql = true) this will show the generated SQL query on console.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using query.uniqueResult(), you should check in your database whether the latest entry is not non-unique entry.

You can try to fetch a list by using query.list() and check if the latest record is available in the list.

Comment: it is the only record in the DATABASE  and i using uniqueResult() because i will update that record if it exsist i dont want duplicate data in my tables

Comment: @muralikolusu
Then you should make the insert operation as Transactional using Transactional annotation. This will treat insert operation as a new transaction and you'll be able to fetch the latest inserted record

Answer (score 0):

Highly recommend that you use bind variables. Concatenating input values to form the query opens you up to SQL injection attacks. Also if you miss quoting the values as needed by the database will cause you to not retrieve any result.